# Text alignment in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

The letters `i` and `y` aren't aligned correctly. the hook of `y` is above the baseline of the `i`. How do I get them to be aligned correctly? The MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,-1);
        \path[anchor=mid] (0,0) node[left] {i} node[right] {y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see by the code:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are more satisfied with the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,-1);
        \path[anchor=mid] (0,0) node[base left] {i} node[base right] {y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks to your answer I could find the best placement: `\path (0,0) node[mid left] {i} node[mid right] {y};`. Thank you very much!